# SQL + Cyrillic support + Parameterized Query + Multiple Choice

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, unicode, ado.net

I have this code so far:

```
string userInput = Textbox1.text;
string query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookName = @Title";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", userInput);
```

and I need this query to support Cyrillic characters, and use N'' for Cyrillic support:

```
SELECT * FROM Books Where BookName = N'UserInput%'
```

i need '%' too because i want to find all books that match the UserInput.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not tested since I don't use .NET but I would probably do it like this.

```
string UserInput = Textbox1.text;
string query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookName like @Title";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", UserInput+"%");
```

Change `=` to `like` in the query, add the `%` to the user input and make sure that the data type for BookName in table Books is of `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 2):

You need Unicode support, not just Cyrillic support.

What is the type of `Books.BookName`? Is it `NVARCHAR(x)`?

`System.String` is already Unicode.

You may try to specify input type manually: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, x)`

Answer (score 2):

You may use LIKE operator, for example

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookName LIKE @Title
```

And to assign parameter a value, you can simply append a "%" to the end of string

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", UserInput + "%");
```